# Как мне написать этот текст (смотрите описание) в виде кода?

Tags: javascript

Как мне это записать кодом: если моя переменная (в данном случае string) содержит **что-то**, кроме букв и цифр, то вывести один символ этого "что-то" в консоль?
То есть, например, вот:

```
var str = 'word #2*(';
```

Символы, которые тут не являются буквой или цифрой (в данном случае, " " и "#*("), должны быть выведены в консоль. Типа, проходимся по массиву символов: если символ != букве или цифре - выводим в консоль. Как это реализовать в js?

Comment: @entithat, Просто я хочу удалять из строки абсолютно всё, кроме букв и цифр

Comment: @entithat, а если, все небуквенные и нечисловые(то есть то же самое, но ->) символы, кроме '#'?

Comment: а что вы потом со строкой делаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var str = 'word #2*(';

console.log(str.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g));
console.log(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '')); // Чтобы удалить
```

Comment: А если удалять все небуквенные и нечисловые(то есть то же самое, но ->) символы, кроме '#'?

Comment: @DenisBredun, то следует изменить регулярное выражение `[^a-zA-Z0-9#]`

Comment: Пасиб :3333333333333

Comment: И вот ещё что: ваш код подойдёт только к моему примеру или ко всем string переменным?

Comment: Окей, спасибо большое!

Comment: Или - `/\W+/g` )

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, кстати `\w` включает и `_`.